# Object has no method, error in script w/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
function Student(){
    var that=this;
    that.SaveChanges=function(){
    //.....
}
function init(){
    that.SaveChanges1();
}
init();
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var student=new Student();  
    });
</script>
```

With jquery-1.4.4.min.js, I could not save changes, because I made error, but rest of the application work.
With jquery-1.7.1.min.js I get error  Object # has no method 'SaveChanges1' and rest of the application does not work.
OR
that.SaveChanges1 is not a function
[Break On This Error]

(77 out of range 4)

What should I do to work like with  jquery-1.4.4.min.js?

Comment: Yes, it is typo error. Or sometimes I call function that does not exist. If I made an error, I do not want to rest of the application does not work, because of this small error.

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you trying to call method SaveChanges1 if it does not exist?

Comment: Because, I can make mistake. But rest of the application should not suffer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try NOT to make errors in your javascript... It's good that it blows up, at least it warns you that something doesn't work! Perhaps you should try running some javascript or selenium tests and perhaps a jslint check to make sure that you don't break any of your javascript functionality!

Comment: It is good idea. But I need something to ignore these error on production, and user can work without problems.

Comment: It still means that something in your application won't work and you won't know about it. Blowing up is jquery's way of telling you you have a problem. You should anyway test things locally before you deploy them on any form of production environment! To be honest I don't know the solution to your problem and even if I did I wouldn't tell you because I think it would be immoral! Good luck with it!

Comment: I know, that part in my example, where I save changes will not work. It is OK. With jquery-1.4.4.min.js I did not have error on another parts, but I upgraded jquery to jquery-1.7.1.min.js and now everytihng is block.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore your errors in some parts of your program, you can do so by using exception handling.  But, you cannot just blindly ignore all errors because when a portion of your script gets an error, that portion of the script has to stop executing as there is no orderly way to continue execution after an error.  The javascript interpreter doesn't know which types of errors are harmless and which types mess up the whole script.

To catch an exception in one part of the script and continue executing other parts, you can add your own exception handling like this:

```
try {
    // your code here that might cause a run-time error
} catch(e) {
    // might want to put some debugging code here so you know that an error was thrown
}

// more code here that will execute even if the previous code threw an error
```

Note: you can use exception handling for run-time execution errors.  You cannot use it for syntax errors that prevent compilation of the javascript code because when that happens, the interpreter can't even understand your code.